# CSS animation - Initial flicker on page reload

Tags: css, css-animations

There is a flicker where all the elements in my animation show up before the animation starts. I thought this was an animation-fill-mode problem, but I can't make it stop doing this no matter what settings to this property I apply. Then I thought it was a webkit thing. But it's now happening on Firefox too. It only happens on page refresh or when one has not visited the page after several hours. When one clicks on the homepage using the NAV menu, it doesn't do this. I also tried -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d; and -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; but these either did nothing or messed up my fancy box 2 lightbox. sorry, it's my first css animation project...I know there is a simple solution to this, but I can't seem to figure out what it is!! Your suggestions are greatly appreciated....

http://theflightfantasticfilm.com

animation css is here

/css/theflightfantastic.css

and

style css is here

/css/style.css

Comment: It looks like your elements all start in their end positions and then when the css finishes loading (or before it begins animating) they are seen there to begin. You might try making their default styles be the start of the animation or hide them until the page loads.

Comment: Could you please add the relevant code to your question, or set up a minimal example on something like jsFiddle. This way your question remains useful to others, even after you fixed your issue. That is after all what SO is for...

Comment: Thank you @lemieuxster....I found my answer here:
https://css-tricks.com/transitions-only-after-page-load/
Transitions Only After Page Load
Published April 27, 2012 by Chris Coyier
and based on one of the users' comments, http://betterhtml.com (Andru Stoicescu), I implemented the following....works great

.element{ 
         opacity:0;  
         transitions are defined here ....
}

.loaded .element{ 
            opacity:1; 
}

jQuery(function($){


//fade the content in
 
$(window).load(function(){
 
 $("body").addClass("loaded");
 $(".element").animate({opacity:1}, 100);
});